# Is there is a way to create constraint greater than or equal relation through code

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working on expandable table cell, and my algorithm is follow:

1. I create two views.
2. Create the height constraint of second view, drag it as IBOutlet to my cell.
3. When cell is selected change status of selected cell.

---

```
class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var expandableCellHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var expandableView: UIView!

    var isExpanded:Bool = false
    {
        didSet
        {
            if !isExpanded {
                self.expandableCellHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0

            } else {
                self.expandableCellHeightConstraint.constant = 120
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, but I want my second view resize related to inner content.

Here are my constraints:

[image]

So, my question is:

What is the best way to write non-strict value to `self.expandableCellHeightConstraint.constant`? Actually I thought of writing something like `self.expandableCellHeightConstraint.constant >= 120`, but as far as I get it is impossible.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint has a "relation" property which can be set to "greaterThanOrEqual".

Comment: yes, but it is read-only according to documentation

Comment: OK, then you have to set it when creating the constraint: `NSLayoutConstraint(..., relatedBy: greaterThanOrEqual, ...)`

Answer (score 10):

As [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305834/is-there-is-a-way-to-create-constraint-greater-than-or-equal-relation-through-co#comment75619250_44305834) suggests, you can create the height constraint in code like this:

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: yourExpandableView,
        attribute: .height,
        relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .notAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 120
)
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
let heightConstraint = yourExpandableView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 120)
```

Then you can set its `isActive` property to true or false whenever you need to enable/disable this constraint. You probably also want to hold this constraint as a property of the class, because constraints become nil, once their property `isActive` is set to false.

I hope it's helpful!